# The series obtained after expanding $(1-x^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}$ where $x\in Q$ and $x^{2}\le1$ convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have tried expanding the series where the terms are

$1-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+\frac{1}{4 2!}x^{4}+......$ .So I have a feeling that it will converge (how do I show it ?).Also will it be convergent to a rational number(as the terms are rational, is there a general way to show when will a series be convergent to a rational number and when it will not?)

Answer (score 1):

By the ratio test, it does converges for $|x|<1$.

And as it converges to $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, the sum is rational when $x^2+q^2=1$ where $q$ is a rational. (I am not aware of a rationality test based on the expression of the general terms.)

Comment: Is there a general way to see when a series converges to a rational number?

Comment: @smita: obviously, if you know that sum converges to $f(x)$, then $f(x)\in\mathbb Q$ is a trivial criterion.

Comment: What theorem should I be using to find the exact limit ?

Comment: @smita: Taylor on an analytic function or the generalized binomial theorem.

Comment: I really didn't get it can you be a bit more precise ?

Comment: @smita: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_and_convergence_of_Taylor_series